# Visual Studio hotkey to switch between code behind and source file?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> often to switch between source and design view.

Does anyone know of a hotkey to switch between the **source file** and its **code behind file**, e.g. between (Default.aspx and Default.aspx.cs)?

Comment: The correct answer is http://stackoverflow.com/a/19097004/481207 by http://stackoverflow.com/users/717267/eduardo-cuomo.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

<kbd>F7</kbd>

Comment: Is that possible to switch from code behind file to source file in Source view(when I switch using shift+F7 it switches me to Design view and I need press shift+F7 twice and it hangs my VS2010)

Comment: @Vladimirs, as outlined in one of the answers below, if you set F7 to trigger `View.ToggleDesigner` it will cycle between code behind and markup source views. No designer nonsense

Comment: This is not the correct answer. F7 is great if you want to see the designer :P see @Vladimirs answer below.  View.ToggleDesigner gives the best working solution. f7 does not work for what the original question was.

Comment: Depends on configuration

Comment: Depends on which version of Visual Studio you are on. I am on VS 2010 and this solution does not work.Setting View.ToggleDesigner to F7 toggles between Code and Design. I think the original question seeks to know the toggle between Code and Source.

Comment: As per WickyNilliams above, the @Vladimirs answer near bottom worked great for me on VS2013.  F7 toggles between code and markup!

Comment: Think this answer is out of date and does not work in recent versions. In VS 2013 F7 will only switch from the .aspx to the .cs but NOT the other way round.

Comment: On VS 2013, View.ToggleDesigner switches from aspx to aspx.cs and if I press again, it switches from aspx.cs to aspx, but it chooses the design view (which I do not want).

Comment: Works on fresh Visual Studio 2022 setup. Shift F7 to switch back

Answer (score 96):

In the *VS2010* the following works:

1. Go to: *Tools* `>` *Options* `>` *Keyboard*
2. Search for "**View.ToggleDesigner**" in "*Show Commands Containing*".
3. Add new shortcut to "**Global**" with <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. F7 now toggles between code behind and markup source view, no designer :)

Comment: This is the correct way. the previous answers do not work in every scenario.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? I am using VS2013, and I only have a View.ToggleDesigner command that fits that search.

Comment: I think it's now called View.ToggleDesigner

Comment: The very fact that it's *incorrectly* called "ToggleDesigner" is precisely why I've never even tried this option to solve this problem. This has nothing to do with the designer!

Comment: Fair warning: this does not work for **website** projects (though it does work for **web applications**). Otherwise, it's the best solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, it switches to design view for me when I come back to the aspx file.

Comment: This worked for me in Visual Studio 2015 as well. Thanks!

Comment: @EduardoCuomo: Thanks, It works for me. I am using Visual Studio 2012. I was looking for this. thanks again.

Comment: I'd upvote 20 as well. So simple and this is something I've wanted since VB6 and there it snuck into the product without me even knowing it.

Comment: I wrote a simple AutoHotkey script to double click on the XAML button to close the designer. Adjust to fit your screen resolution and window configuration. I assigned the hotkey Ctrl-Shift-X:
^+x::
if (WinActive("ahk_exe devenv.exe")) {
 Click, 195, 560, 2
}
return

Comment: Can confirm this worked for me in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Can confirm this worked for me in Visual Studio 2022 :)

Answer (score 44):

Yep just <kbd>F7</kbd>

Look at [this](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e5f902a8-5bb5-4cc6-907e-472809749973&displaylang=en&tm) poster for C# VS2008 shortcuts

You can also bind it to any combination of keys you like, go to tools, options (show all settings) environment, keybord, Show Commands for View.ViewCode and change to your liking.

**Added by [Rob Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/832/rob-cooper):**

For 2005 Users: [Visual C# 2005 Keyboard Shortcut Reference Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c15d210d-a926-46a8-a586-31f8a2e576fe&DisplayLang=en)

For 2010 Users: [Visual C# 2010 Keyboard Shortcut Reference Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=92ced922-d505-457a-8c9c-84036160639f)

**Edit 08 Sept 2014**

There don't seem to be posters beyond 2010 but there is a website for VS2012, VS2013 and VS14: [Visual Studio Shortcuts](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2013/)

Comment: Dude, why you have not got a +1 for the poster link, I do not know. Far more useful than just the one keystroke. +1 from me.

Comment: I didn't want to vote you up but Rob Cooper made me do it :-)

Answer (score 23):

For those trying to do this (switch *from* the code view *to* markup view) in VS2012, I had to go `Tools > Options > Keyboard`, then select

- Keyboard Mapping Scheme as "(default)"
- View.ToggleDesigner as the command
- Use new shortcut in "Text Editor"
- Set the shortcut key to <kbd>F7</kbd>

This results in <kbd>F7</kbd> switching both ways from the markup view to the code view and vice versa.

Before doing this I had to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> twice to get to markup from the code view.

Comment: Thank you. The only true "toggle" answer I see on this page.

Comment: This does in fact work for VS2015, but I'd also add that you do not need to change the Keyboard Mapping Scheme.

Comment: You must also actually *enable* the Web Forms designer for this to work. I was trying to get rid of it and just toggle between the ASPX and codebehind. Once I reenabled it, the above steps worked.

Comment: This was the answer that worked for me with VS 2017. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

In VS 2013 it is

1. Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard
2. Type "View.Toggle" or "View.ToggleDesigner" (the command could be either depending on the version of VS) in `Show Commands Containing:`
3. Make Sure `Use new shortcut in:` is set to `Global`
4. Put cursor in `Press shortcut keys:` box
5. Hit <kbd>F7</kbd> then the `Assign` button

Comment: In VS 2008, hitting F7 at that point (or elsewhere, to do the usual "build solution" command) had no effect, until I closed the TrackIR 4 application (C:\Program Files (x86)\NaturalPoint\TrackIR4\TrackIR.exe).  F7, F9 and F12 appear to all be trapped by some versions of that application.  https://forums.naturalpoint.com/viewtopic.php?t=12544&p=57648

Answer (score 9):

In case <kbd>F7</kbd> does not work for you, go to "Tools - Import and Export settings - Reset all settings" and choose "Web development" template to reset to.

Comment: Or set F7 to `View.ToggleDesigner`. It's a misnomer action, it actually toggles source/code behind.

Comment: @WickyNilliams Not necessarily. My coworker updated his settings without changing to Web Development template and F7 would toggle between code behind and the actual designer view.

Comment: View.ToggleDesigner changes its behaviour according to if you've got Design View enabled (and set as default) or not.

Comment: @Kyle same thing happens for me.

Comment: @NickG do you know how to disable Design View?

Comment: @AlexanderPuchkov To disable design view in Visual Studio, go to Tools > Options > HTML Designer > General and uncheck the "Enable" box

Comment: After I disabled design view like you describe, View.ToggleDesigner switches from aspx to aspx.cs but not the other way around (vs2013).

Answer (score 4):

Just drop the <kbd>shift</kbd> key, it's just <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

When in code view use <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> to get to the designer. When in the designer use <kbd>F7</kbd> to get back to code.

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp</kbd> to toggle between design view and code behind.

Comment: CTRL+PageUp does not toggle between design view and code behind, but it DOES toggle between the three: source/split/design views. Nice!

Comment: That's actually what I ended up in this question looking for! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Shift + F7 works for me when class Form1 is first in namespace.