# Visual Studio 2008 - jump to line number shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

I can go to a specific line number by double clicking in the status bar in Visual Studio.  Is there a keyboard shortcut that does the same thing?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>

Check out all the keyboard shortcuts at:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e5f902a8-5bb5-4cc6-907e-472809749973&displaylang=en

Comment: cheeky ;)  Giving the correct answer and then changing it to the 'real' answer after the OP marked the first one as accepted.

Answer (score 17):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>G</kbd> works for me.

If it doesn't work for you, you can always map whatever shortcut you want under Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard.

**EDIT:** Yes, as @Brian mentions, the command in this case is `Edit.GoTo`

I just realised that the default in C# settings for this command is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, whereas in VB Settings, there is no default keyboard short - it's mapped to show the immediate window - strange I think. I swapped the mappings so that the two environment behave the same.

Comment: Thank you for being the only answer that says what the actual command is.

Comment: I was going crazy trying to look for Edit.GoToLine...

Answer (score 1):

Every IDE or even text editor I have ever used either uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> for this purpose.

I assume this could stand for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Line or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Goto

Comment: Careful, Ctrl + L deletes a line in Visual Studio 2008. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yep <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320119/visual-studio-hotkey-to-switch-between-code-behind-and-source-file#320151) you can get a nice Shortcut poster.