# Visual Studio 2015 double-clicking the line-number in the status bar does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual studio 2010 has a feature 'go to line' by double-clicking the line number in the status bar.

This feature does not work in the Visual studio 2015.

Double-clicking the status bar do nothing. (also double-clicking the INS/OVR to switch between them does not work since VS2015)

Is there any way to get it back?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333563/visual-studio-2008-jump-to-line-number-shortcut

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev there is no there an answer about status bar, only for shortcuts

Comment: If there was, this would be a duplicate rather that related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be fixed in Update 2 RC2. Once again I can double-click on the line number. Yay!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it was existing and I missing it too, so used to click on the status bar ! You need to use Ctrl + G