# Keyboard shortcut to toggle between Markup and Code-behind

Tags: webforms, visual-studio-2013

In vs2012, the f7 key toggles between the Markup and the Codebehind of aspx/ascx/masterpage files. Vs2013 used to behave the same way before I reinstalled my system. Now it will only go from Markup to Codebehind but never the other way. I can get it to switch to the HTML Designer but I'm not interested in that.

I tried to fix it with no avail. Here were my steps:

1. Create a brand new Webforms project to ensure that corrupt aspx and aspx.cs files were not the root of the problem.
2. Goto `Tools > Options > Enviroment > Keyboard`; there I set unique key bindings for ViewCode, ViewMarkup, and ViewDesigner.
3. Goto `Tools > Options > HTML Designer` and check off "Enable HTML designer" and "Auto keyboard switching";
4. Restart Visual Studio

I also tried importing my Keyboard settings from VS2012 into VS2013.

Comment: The best I can come up with is to (1) Enable the HTML Designer (2) Use the `Shift`+`F7` shortcut twice.

Comment: See top answer and comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320119/visual-studio-hotkey-to-switch-between-code-behind-and-source-file

Answer (score 2):

I decided to import **ALL** of my settings from VS2012 instead of just the keyboard shortcuts and that solved the problem. This at least shows it is possible.