# Open Visual Studio Integrated Design Environment

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I somehow managed to close the visual design tab of my project where you drag component from the toolbox to. I've tried every view I can think of. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 if anyone can tell me how to re-open the design view(not the code) that'd be great as I don't know my way around every aspect of visual studio.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio hotkey to switch between code behind and source file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320119/visual-studio-hotkey-to-switch-between-code-behind-and-source-file)

Comment: similar but not a duplicate as i've closed the view and can not get back into it and the shortcut they suggested does not work. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Alright well I figured I'd ask for some ideas before doing my last resort of saving the code and a screenshot of the design view and just re-building it. I appreciated you guys trying to help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you right-click the "FormName.vb" file in Solution Explorer, you can click "View Designer." Alternatively, you can click "Open With..." and choose Visual Basic Form Editor from the list.

Comment: Well that works on the old project so thanks for the head ups but I 've already rebuilt the form and continued on with coding =)

Answer (score 0):

Try using XXX.Designer.cs from your Solution Explorer 
hope it'll help

Comment: I don't see any myprogramname.Designer.cs in my solution explorer

Comment: @AndrewNichols: That's because this answer assumes you are using C# and not VB.

Comment: @AndrewNichols will you please tell us that on which language or which kind of project you are woking with ? Can you post a Screenshot

Comment: The question is tagged `vb.net`!

Comment: @TheBlueDog oops Sorry