# Visual Studio 2017/2019 Razor page keyboard shortcut to view cshtml.cs file(code behind)

Tags: visual-studio-2017, razor-pages, visual-studio-2019

Using older asp pages you could view the code behind pressing the F7 key.  This short cut does not work for VS17/19.

I have tried some of the suggestions "[Visual Studio hotkey to switch between code behind and source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320119/visual-studio-hotkey-to-switch-between-code-behind-and-source-file/19097004#19097004)" that did not work.

This is driving me crazy, and I know that it is a very simple fix, but i cannot find anything on the web about it.

So the goal

Press F7 or other function key to view the cshtml.cs file for the associated .cshtml file.

Answer (score 12):

There is a command available to do this for [Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/).  It does not work for all .cshtml files (i.e. MVC views).

You can bind the command by configuring it in the Keyboard options.  The command is called `ProjectandSolutionContextMenus.Item.ToggleRazorView` (not the most intuitive, I know).  In the screenshot, I've already bound it to the <kbd>F7</kbd> key:
[image: Showing command bound to F7]

(note: this was previously reported through [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/315100/f7-navigation-doesnt-work-in-razor-pages.html) (also sometimes called VS Feedback), which is a great way to make sure your feedback reaches the product team.)